# How can I get the index value of a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Using the following approach I am able to create a dictionary of values:

```
{ p.id : {'total': p.total} for p in p_list}
```

This results in `{34:{'total':334}, 53:{'total: 123} ... }`

I would also like to list an index from the list so that I know which position `p.id` was in. I made a list like this:

```
 c_list = [x for x in range(len(p_list))]
```

And then tried to see how `c` could also be listed as part of the result. I thought I needed something like this:

```
{ (p,c) for p in p_list for c in c_list}
```

but when I tried to implement it, I could not get `c` to be a value in the dictionary:

```
{ (p.id, c : {'total': p.total, 'position': c}) for p in p_list for c in c_list}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to get index as well as the item from the iterable:

```
{ (p.id, ind) : {'id': p.id, 'position': ind} for ind, p in enumerate(p_list)}
```

**Update:**

```
{ p.id : {'id': p.id, 'position': ind} for ind, p in enumerate(p_list)}
```

Help on `enumerate`:

```
>>> print enumerate.__doc__
enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable

Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
    (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get a `keys must be a string` error if I try this. I think this is because it tries to use `(p.id, ind)` as a key value for the dictionary; I can't figure out how to avoid it though.

Comment: @celenius Works fine for me, tuples are valid keys for dicts.

Comment: But if you know the index, why would you want to query the dictionary (using the index as part of the tuple key) for the index? :P  That's my question.

Comment: @ShashankGupta sorry - that was a typo. I am trying to just have the first value as the key dict, I suppose `(p.id, ind)[0]` would work?

Comment: @celenius just use : `p.id: {'id': p.id, 'position': ind}` if you only want `p.id` as key.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `enumerate`. It's a generator function that returns tuples of the form: (i, iterable[i]).

```
{ p.id : {'id': p.id, 'position': i} for i, p in enumerate(p_list)}
```